# Javascript ContentEditable &NBSP; replace issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

"`&nbsp;`" in the text I am having a problem with deletion.

The details are as follows;

If a sentence starts with a "space", the value I get from the relevant div is as follows;

```
<div>&NBSP; bla bla bla bla </div>
```

If a sentence ends with a "space", the value I get from the relevant div is as follows;

```
<div> bla bla bla bla&NBSP;</div>
```

If the spaces are in the middle of a sentence, there is no problem, but if there are spaces at the beginning or the end of the sentence, when reading the value, only the spaces at the beginning or end of the "&NBSP;" writes as.

```
editDiv.replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm,"").replace('&NBSP;',' ');
```

I am using the method but the problem persists.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `.replace()` would do the trick. I changed the `&NBSP;` to `&nbsp;` since the former just confused the browser and isn't valid syntax

```js
let div = document.querySelector('.contentEditable');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replaceAll(">&nbsp;", ">").replace("&nbsp;</", "</")
console.log(div.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class='contentEditable'>
  <div>&nbsp; bla bla&nbsp;bla bla&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kinglish solves my problem in your answer, but now I found the source of the problem.

I made "toLocaleUpperCase('tr-TR')" on the js side during text entry to the relevant div. Removing it fixed the problem.